# Best way to work out if a path is in an include or exclude list in python

Tags: python, watchdog

I am writing a python program to backup files from a series of watched directories.
I am using Watchdog to detect changes to the file system. All that gives is a list of changed files and folders.

The application has the option to have include and exclude folder lists, but i cant work out how to match the paths to see if they should be excluded or included.

The issue is when you have a tree and the user selects to include a folder that is inside of an excluded one.

example file tree

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5
```

Includes

```
/folder1
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```

Excluded

```
/folder1/folder2
```

I thought about using startswith() to compare the starts of the path section of the string returned by watchdog, but then `/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5` would match on the includes and the exclude folder lists.

If someone could suggest the best way to approach this I would be very grateful. I could make it work easily if i was using os.walk to recurse through the directories but just given a list I cant work out how to do it. Its driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, you want to give priority to the most-nested depth.  So `'/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5` is *included*.

I would get your data into a lookup table like this:

```
lookup = {'/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4':'include','/folder1/folder2':'exclude','/folder1':'include'}
```

Then just loop over your query in reverse order, stripping off one directory at a time until you get a match:

```
folder = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5'.split('/')
for i in reversed(range(len(folder) + 1)):
    check = '/'.join(folder[:i])
    if lookup.get(check):
        print('{}: {}'.format(check,lookup.get(check)))
        break

#/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4: include
```

Comment: I have run some tests and this looks like its perfect. Only thing I had to change was if lookup.get(check) != None: as get() returns the value of that key in the dict  or None. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Deano123 well `None` is false in a boolean context so the two statements are semantically equivalent in most situations.  Still, glad it helped, cheers.

Comment: That is true, but the statement returns the value for the key, so include and exclude are not equivalent to True are they? I am quite new to python and havent dont any real development for years, this is my first big project so I am probably wrong, but it would be good to understand why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a path `f` and if I understand your question correctly, this may work

```
f.startswith(tuple(includes)) and not f.startswith(tuple(excludes))
```

Answer (score 0):

As another possibility, the action (i.e. include or exclude) that should apply to any given path is the most specific.  So, you might approach the problem by placing your configuration in a structure like:

```
rules = [("/folder1", "include"), ("/folder1/folder2/...", "exclude"), ...]
```

You can then determine which action to apply for a given path using a function such as:

```
def get_action(path, rules):
    action = None
    depth = None
    for filter, filter_action in rules:
        if path.startswith(filter):
            filter_depth = filter.count(os.sep)
            if depth is None or filter_depth > depth:
                depth = filter_depth
                action = filter_action
    return action
```

This will then return the action, that is "include" or "exclude", or if no rule is defined for the path `None`.  The definition I've given is fairly inefficient, and there are many ways it could be improved, but the basic idea is to look for the most specific rule for a given path and follow that action.